# Merge xml file in ant script

Tags: xml, xpath, ant, xmltask

Have such a requirement:

Insert the following servelet into web.xml if not already there:

```
  <servlet>
   <description>My Servlet</description>
   <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.tom.servlet.MyServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/myServlet/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

I am using [XMLTask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/#examples) in my ant script

Tried the following script,but failed:

```
<xmltask source="${env.My_HOME}/WEB-INF/web.xml" dest="${env.My_HOME}/WEB-INF/web.xml" report="false">
        <copy property="servletfound" path="/web-app/servlet[servlet-name='myServlet']/text()" />
        <insert unless="servletfound" path="/web-app/servlet[last()]" position="after">
            <![CDATA[
            <servlet>
   <description>My Servlet</description>
   <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.tom.servlet.MyServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/myServlet/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
        ]]>
        </insert>
    </xmltask>
```

My question is how to detect that servlet is there or not, because I should avoid to insert twice.
Sounds my xpath grammar is not correct. Please help.

Comment: try this /web-app/servlet[count(./servlet-class)>1] and this need some improvements too

Comment: what's this meaning?

Answer (score 0):

The Xpath you tried :

```
/web-app/servlet[servlet-name='myServlet']/text()
```

...return text nodes that is **direct child of `<servlet>`**, which doesn't exist in the XML sample posted. If you meant to return text nodes that is **direct child of `<servlet-name>`** instead, the XPath should've been something like this  :

```
/web-app/servlet/servlet-name[.='myServlet']/text()
```